# nginx rewrite remove html except if URL contains string

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

We need to redirect all links containing html to non html, example:

domain.com/post.html -> domain.com/post
domain.com/2010/10/post.html -> domain.com/2010/10/post

however we need to exclude URL's that contain 'plugins' in the path, example:

domain.com/wp-content/plugins/something/test.html should not redirect.

Trying to accomplish this with:

`rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;`

and adding a negative lookbehind:

`rewrite ^(?!plugins)(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;`

any variation I try seems to have an issue. Or will still remove .html from the URL even if contains plugins in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`rewrite ^(?!/[^/]+/plugins/)(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;`

Tests:

```
/post.html         ==> domain.com/post
/post.html?foo=bar ==> domain.com/post?foo=bar
/2010/10/post.html ==> domain.com/2010/10/post
/wp-content/plugins/something/test.html (no match)
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` ... `$` - anchor at beginning and end
- `(?!/[^/]+/plugins/)` - negative lookahead expecting `/plugins/` in second sub-directory
- `(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$` - capture anything before `.html`, and capture anything after (if any)

Comment: Exactly what was needed, thank you for explanation as well